# Can't upgrade Xamarin.Forms NuGet package for Android project

Tags: xamarin, nuget, xamarin.forms, nuget-package

When I am trying to upgrade Xamarin.Forms NuGet package from 2.0-2.1 to 2.3.1.114 (latest stable at the moment) I get the following error (even with new blank projects) is there a way to fix it?

[image]

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 23.3.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.  

    0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this option for your project:

[image]

Comment: wierd, but it works with all other versions of Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 package

Answer (score 1):

This error is most probably because your xamarin forms version is not compatible with `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 23.3.0` available through NuGet. Check [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/65287/unable-to-find-a-version-of-xamarin-forms-that-is-compatible-with-xamarin-android-support-v4-23-3) thread on xamarin official forum. As per this thread, 23.3 is not supported by Xamarin forms. On more possible reason is that your xamarin form version is not compatible with the latest update. You can try updating forms to latest version. In case if that doesn't work, then probably you should continue with the version you already have.